# ¿Marcar varios puntos en Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic, cordova

Tengo un problema con los markers en el mapa de google maps, he estado tratando de implementar un mapa de google con api de javascript, trabajo con ionic 1 y angularjs y este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora.
El problema es que solo me marca donde estoy y no me muestra los markers de los comercios que obtengo con el json.

Javascript y Cordova geolocalization

```
var options = {
  timeout: 10000,
  enableHighAccuracy: true
 };

 $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position) {

 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

 var mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 17,
    disableDefaultUI: true
 };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latLng,
   map: map,
 });
 // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
 marker.setMap(map);

}, function(error) {
  console.log("Could not get location");
});

$.getJSON("http://www.kupomcity.com/gamma/api_v2.php?_opt=comercios&_act=json", function(json1) {
  $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
  //console.log (data);
    if (data.lat != '' && data.lng != '') {
      console.log("json lat: " + data.lat + "json lng: " + data.lng);
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
      });

      marker.setMap($scope.map);
    };
  });
})
```

Comment: has intentado hacerlo de esta forma : https://www.create.net/support/218-how-to-pin-point-multiple-locations-on-google-maps.html

Comment: o de esta manera :  https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-mark-multiple-locations-on-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

cómo estás? En la documentación de Google Maps está explicada la manera correcta de colocar multiples marcadores en el mapa. 
Te dejo el JSFiddle oficial de Google en donde explica la manera de agregar varios marcadores al mapa utilizando un array (el cual podría ser los datos de tu archivo JSON) - https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Básicamente utiliza un iterador, en cada iteración se agrega un nuevo marcador utilizando la instancia del mapa ya inicializada.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Saludos!